# Change default bounty reason

Tags: feature-request, bounty

When [starting a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), users can select a [reason](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) from a list of predefined choices. In the next step, it is possible to add some custom text to detail this reason.

A popular reason for starting a bounty is
    *Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.*

Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44204723), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44075067), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44043697), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44106848), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44072395). Note that I found these manually, they are not exactly hard to stumble upon.

In most of these cases, OP is not actually looking for such an answer. This appears to mostly be the case when no custom reason is filled out. For example, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44204723) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44075067) in the above list seem to merely seek attention, while [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44043697) is actually looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources. This is clear from the custom text detailing the reason for starting that bounty.

**My hunch.** (Some) users don't read all text in the pop-up for selecting a bounty reason. They immediately click the *next* button and move on. Can they? Yes. Why? Well... there is a default.

[image]

**The problem.** Most users who start a bounty on a question do so, I believe,
1. on their own question; and
2. to draw attention to their question.
The default reason for starting a bounty does *not* reflect this.

**Proposed solution.** Change the default reason for starting a bounty to
    *This question has not received enough attention.*

Comment: 100% agree. Excellent feature request and analysis. Would upvote again.

Comment: Nah, just do not select reason at all. Start with no selected reason.

Comment: @Braiam you're asking for heatmaps of which one people will click fastest so they can dismiss the dialogue faster

Comment: Simply change the default to "I wish to diminish my reputation." It works both ways. (Hopefully the list takes into account whether there _are_ any answers.)

Comment: We should probably start with some statistics of how often each option is chosen. If it's the default one then that doesn't bode well for this feature request. Perhaps SEDE can help with this?

Comment: @TylerH "If it's the default one" - do you mean, "If it's the _suggested_ default one"?

Comment: @DocRoot '*suggested* default' is redundant/not a thing; either there is a default option (the one that goes into effect if you don't manually pick a different one), or there isn't. Currently, the default choice is "authoritative reference needed".

Comment: Change it so there is *no* default selected (as suggested by @Braiam). But, *also* change the order the options are listed in to reflect the most commonly selected option on top and ordered by descending popularity. From a UX point of view, the options should be ordered in descending popularity (so people have to read fewer options). If the list was of very short options (e.g. countries), then alpha-sorting is also reasonable (perhaps with the most popular one/two/few at the top of the list, if the list is long). In this case, having a default imposes the designer's assumptions upon the user.

Comment: @TylerH The OP is suggesting a new default as the _proposed solution_, it is this "suggested default" (or "proposed default") that I think you are referring to in your earlier comment, rather than the "current default" - which is how your comment is written? That was all.

Comment: @DocRoot Ah, no I'm referring to the *current* default, not whatever default OP might be wanting in his post.

Comment: I would go one step further. Or actually take a step back. I would say "draw attention" is... a pretty flimsy and uninformative reason. If we could pick more than one reason for a single bounty, it would virtually never be wrong to choose "draw attention" as one of them, if we're simply taking the words at face value. I guess "draw attention" is really a euphemism for "no answers yet (or only unsalvageably crappy answers so far), please answer!". Do we really need a separate bounty reason for "please, so desperate for an answer that we don't care if it draws from credible sources or not!"?

Comment: Seriously? How does _this_ get to 158? Seriously? I mean... ... ... seriously?

Comment: You may want to amend your request to explicitly ask for the options to be  *reordered*. The default should be at the top, of course, but based on the data below, reordering the others may make sense as well.

Comment: Are you sure it's an good idea to make less clicks in this case? Most of the "Draw attention" bouties I see are on questions with no research effort whatsoever, badly written or simple dupes, where askers will feel good to post 50 unicorn points to avoid their duty. Putting an bounty on these will lock our ability to close vote, and some will even be glad to upvote it just because of the shiny amount of UP in the banner. IMM setting "Draw attention" as the default will just make it easier to lock crappy questions.

Comment: @Kaiido I don't see how this would affect that in any way. People who would do that will still do that, and people who otherwise wouldn't do that will not be any more enticed to do that because of this change.

Comment: @TinyGiant I welcome any and all constructive criticism, is there anything you think can be improved in my post? Or is there another reason for your surprise?

Comment: The reason for my surprise is the attention this question is getting with respect to the triviality of the change.

Comment: @TinyGiant - See [Parkinson's law of triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) or [Sayre's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayre%27s_law).

Comment: But ... it's sorted alphabetically! And the default value of an array index is 0. It's so ... technically correct.

Comment: @TinyGiant 1. As you say, the change is trivial to make. 2. The change is obvious and intuitive. Even a tiny bit of data backs up making the change (even if the proposed reasoning isn't 100% true). 3. It's quick and easy to agree with. There's not really any debate that it would be an improvement. I think these factors combine to lead to a lot of quick (and reasonable in this case) upvotes by people who just happen to see it.

Answer (score 58):

Some [hard data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/677687) - on posts since the beginning of the year (1/1/2017).

```
5120 | Draw attention
1950 | Authoritative reference needed
 802 | Canonical answer required
 268 | Improve details
 161 | Reward existing answer
  59 | Current answers are outdated
```

The same is true if you look at data on posts since the beginning of 2015, in roughly the same proportions.

Looking at only self-offered bounties since the beginning of the year, [it's the same story](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/677698):

```
4776 | Draw attention
1821 | Authoritative reference needed
 745 | Canonical answer required
 254 | Improve details
 110 | Reward existing answer
  53 | Current answers are outdated
```

Comment: On the other hand, this shows that nearly 25% of bounties are looking for an authoritative reference. An authoritative reference is a particularly rare case and, being extremely generous, I'd imagine only applies to <5% of questions.

Comment: True, @Rob - but it's also nowhere near a majority and shows that more study is needed before concluding it's a real problem. Wouldn't be hard to produce a list of questions those bounties were offered on for review.

Comment: Does this data not scream that drawing attention should be the default option? We might "correct" the bounty reason for some questions, but we *definitely* save a lot of users a click.

Comment: It looks like people just hit the next button too quickly without changing the reason, hence the large amount for 'Authoritative reference needed'.

Comment: So…it isn't true that *most* people just blindly click through the dialog without reading its contents, but it is still true that *many* people do. I suppose you see the glass as half-full, too. :-)

Comment: Does this change with user time and or reputation in SO? I would expect people who just earned the privilege of setting bounties will be more in a hurry to have answers/attention and *might* dismiss the dialog. (I am not confident enough to tweak the query for that purpose.)

Comment: Agree with @Justastudent. The default option should be the one chosen by most people. The data supports the request.

Comment: This data shows that the current default is not causing a *problem* as OP seems to indicate. It *does*, however, show that there's room for optimization; setting the default to "Draw attention" would speed up the process for a **majority** of bounty creator.

Comment: @Rob 23.3% to be more precise.

Comment: @CodyGray I think that's enough reason to *not* have defaults.

Comment: @Braiam Like I said earlier, then the most or second-most clicked one will be that which dismisses the dialogue / moves on fastest

Comment: @TylerH I never said that *authoritative reference needed* is the most selected reason. I noticed that it was selected more often than I would expect. My actual question would be to change the default to what I would expect to be selected most often. This expectation is confirmed by the data in this answer. I would like to refrain from making any claims on the number of bounty reasons that does not match the intent of the bounty starter, but I definitely think that there is a substantial number of them. How do you conclude that "data shows that the current default is not causing a problem"?

Comment: If my SQL is correct (please [check it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/678191)!), apparently of those `1950` Authoritative reference needed, `1518` of them (**77.8%**) were bounties posted on answers that currently had zero answers at the time. That really sounds like the poster wanted *attention*, not authority...? Certainly, they couldn't be dissatisfied with existing answers, since there were none. (cc @Justastudent)

Comment: @Justastudent I never said you said that... seems like an odd claim to invent. At any rate, the gist of your post is that the default option is problematic, because you've noticed some questions where that bounty reason seems erroneously applied, and then you seem to suggest that maybe many users are ending up with this option because it's the default and they're speedily clicking through. The data from Undo show a different story: The default choice is picked **less than 25% of the time**, which doesn't support your hunch.

Comment: @Justastudent What the data *do* show is that your ultimate proposal: change the default to 'draw attention' is a good one, because that's *by far* the most-picked option. In short, your proposal is a good one, but for reasons other than what you are positing. AKA you suggest the right thing for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @apsillers it's possible the bounty posters interpret that reason as "dissatisfied with the state of the current answers". If the state is null, that would certainly be dissatisfying!

Comment: @TylerH My apologies, I think I got the majority part from a comment of Undo and erroneously mixed it up in my reply to you. Still, I argue that my hunch, namely that the default is chosen more than one could reasonably expect, is neither confirmed nor debunked by the data. As Rob wrote, 25% *seems* like a lot. As Undo wrote, we don't know for sure. In any case, I think we all agree here :-) Again, apologies for putting words in your mouth. Cheers :-)

Comment: @TylerH Possible, but highly unlikely. It's a well established fact that being first on a list induces greater selection of that item. Even if we say only 5% of those are simply because it's first, that's nearly 100 bounties with the wrong reason. "Draw more attention" is absolutely a better default reason. Most of the other reasons could even be called specific subcategories of it, which means "attention" is still applicable and would make the reason "more correct" more often.

Comment: Could we also have quality insight from this data ? Which categories have the most negative reception ?

Comment: @jpmc26 read all of my comments, you're basically agreeing with me.

Comment: To me, this does not answer the question. There's no guidance whether or not the default reason should be changed. This answer should have been a comment. Why should I vote on pure data without an action?

Comment: @ThomasWeller On meta, "discussion" answers are permitted. This one here just adds some data for users to consider and leaves it at that. It's fine.

Answer (score 39):

Some additional data, building on top of [Undo's work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349899/710446):

- Undo found that during 2017 so far, 1950 bounties were of the type "Authoritative reference needed"
- Based on [this forked query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/678191/845776/), 1518 of those 1950 bounties were offered on currently-unanswered questions.

This means that three-quarters of the time users asked for an "Authoritative reference" they didn't even have any answer at all yet, which suggests to me that the OP really wanted attention. It seems unusual that the OP would insist (strongly enough to expend reputation points) on authoritative references, when they had no answers at all yet.

Based on this evidence, I'd lean toward the conclusion that most of the time the "Authoritative reference needed" bounty reason is used, it is a mistake.

Comment: Yet, that doesn't mean that one should be selected.

Comment: And neither do I suggest that anything be selected by default `:)` Honestly, I don't have enough UI experience to say whether an option should be default-selected (certainly, no default selection sounds pretty reasonable to me at first glance). However, I would recommend moving "more attention" to the top of the list, considering its overwhelming popularity.

Comment: Indeed, I am quite confident that most people interpret *looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources* as merely a verbose way to say *looking for a good answer*; and whether there are already bad answers or no answers, wouldn't *anyone* looking for *any* answer be looking for a **good** answer? So "authoritative reference needed" is arguably tantamount to "draw attention". (By "more attention" we don't mean "(more) crappy answers", do we?) Honestly, I don't think it would hurt to simply remove "authoritative reference needed" entirely, or merge the two reasons.

Comment: I think you may be making too large of an assumption. The bounty system is a guarantee of attention. Your question gets higher visibility for a week (on an increasing sliding scale as the week progresses). The *reason* for posting a bounty on a question is that you want an answer. What kind of answer or why you want an answer is independent of the desire for an answer; If I post a question and want an authoritative answer, & the question gets no answers, my bounty is to draw more attention (because bumping is disallowed). I ***still want an authoritative answer***, even with no answers yet.

Answer (score -20):

Do we really want people to just "click through"? Catering to the lowest denominator? If that's what we want, we should just make the default: I want these reputation to be deducted invariably from my account. Or asking for the first son, or [maybe money if we don't have Google problem](https://xkcd.com/792/)...

In any case, the default should be sane default, in this case, there's no "sane default", therefore no default should be the default as it's the sanest default, other options wouldn't be accurate in all cases anyways.

Comment: Allowing the most commonly used option as default does not feel (to me) like "want[ing] people to just click through", but rather improving UX. These people already take the time to click the relevant option. That aside though, I could agree with the no default option.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier allowing 75% of the users that don't read to continue not reading is perpetuating the no need of reading, which exacerbates the complains with current and past generations of not being able to think.

Comment: Making people click something won't make them actually read what they click. There's no reason to throw in a speed bump that will slow everyone down with zero benefit.

Comment: @jpmc26 making people not click something just perpetuates and reinforces the conduct of not reading. I will go as many mental hops for anyone if that puts enough mental barriers to prevent people from doing stupid stuff.

Comment: Where is it suggested that we would be "_making_ people not click something"?  We wouldn't be disallowing anyone from doing anything. We would be automatically selecting the most commonly selected option, which would make the process slightly more efficient for as many people as possible. Forcing people to select an option won't do anything at all, except make the process slightly less efficient for those who select the most commonly selected option.

Comment: @Braiam: Let's say SO does what you ask by not selecting a default choice. Would you want the most common choice at the top, so people find it soonest? Would you want it at the bottom, so (most) people have to read all the options before they come the one they actually wanted?

Comment: @Michael I don't care how they are ordered. Just that there's a barrier that makes people read.

Comment: @Braiam So you prefer bad UX so that the people that won't read it anyway still won't and those that do are hindered?

Comment: @Braiam The barrier doesn't make anyone read. Those who don't want to read will click the most convenient option and press next. Do you want to add a reading comprehension test to it? That might make people read.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder no, I want an UX that doesn't allow brain dead users to continue acting like brain dead users.

Comment: @jpmc26 well, at least I wouldn't require them to not read. There are many ways you can spun it, but having a default is requiring people to not read anything and click through. If by not requiring people to not read makes them read, I feel satisfied.

Comment: @Braiam When you work that one out please let every application developer/maintainer know so they can fix everything.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't need to, they already did. Way past the time, just that it's so simple that most devs/maintainers just ignore it. Add friction.

Comment: @Braiam "well, at least I wouldn't require them to not read." This statement is ridiculous and represents an intentional misreading of what others have written. Of course you're expected to read it; that's why it's there to read. But we can't *force* anyone to understand it without some kind of comprehension test, and even then, you'd have to craft it so that Googling the answers required skimming them enough to pick the right one. Forcing someone to click something *only* forces them to click something, not read what's around it. All it does is *annoy*, without making anyone read.

Comment: How is preselecting a default action _requiring_ anyone to not read? It does nothing of the sort. It _allows_ people to continue not reading where they would otherwise have not read, and it allows people to continue reading where they would otherwise have read. This change will literally affect **nothing** with regards to reading or comprehension of the text presented, at all, whatsoever.